# In which file enumeration of PCIe devices is located in Linux kernel for ARM based system?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I am working to develop PCIe drivers for a custom ARM based platform. As a starting point I have started to look into Linux kernel 4.15.9 code. I am unable to locate the relevant PCIe driver files. In particular I am interested in PCIe device enumeration and configuration. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCIe driver code is divided in 4 section.

1 - PCIe subsystem code

> This is the generic PCIe subsystem code which takes care of Bus scan,
>   MSI allocation, BAR allocation, etc.
>
> Path - driver/pci/*

2 - PCIe host controller IP generic code

> This is specific to the host controller. That means for a certain host
>   in a platform, PCIe subsystem will communicate via the APIs provided
>   by this code.
>
> Path - drivers/pci/dwc/*
>   Example - DWC host
>   NOTE - Not all controller manufacturer has a separate folder like DWC
>   (Synopsys).

3 - PCIe host controller initialization platform specific code

> This is specific to the PCIe IP and it will be specific for a SoC.
>   Every SoC will have their own chip specific code to initialize the
>   controller. So the APIs in this part will be used by the "PCIe host
>   generic code"
>
> Path - drivers/pci/host/*

4 - PCIe capabilities

> This code segment contain capabilities processing like AER, DPC. ASPM,
>   etc.
>
> Path - drivers/pci/pcie/*